# digital root code gives wrong answer and an error

Tags: javascript, html

I’m really new to javascript, and i’m working on a project for my class. I needed to make a digital root calculator and when I finally thought I got it, it just alerts that the digital root is a random number like 1 or 2 before giving the actual root,,,then the alert says “NaN” and the page breaks. I’m not entirely sure what’s wrong

```js
function digroot() {

  var num1 = document.getElementById("root").value
  var num2 = document.getElementById("root2").value
  var num3 = document.getElementById("root3").value
  var num4 = document.getElementById("root4").value
  var num5 = document.getElementById("root5").value

  var sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2) + Number(num3) + Number(num4) + Number(num5);

  var sumstr = sum.toString();

  var total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; sumstr.length; i++) {
    total += Number(sumstr[i]);
    alert(total);
  }

  alert(total);
}

document.getElementById("rootchecker").addEventListener('click', digroot);
```

```html
<form><input type="text" name="root" id="root">
  <input type="text" name="root2" id="root2">
  <input type="text" name="root3" id="root3">
  <input type="text" name="root4" id="root4">
  <input type="text" name="root5" id="root5">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="rootchecker" id="rootchecker">Check digital root</button>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: `sumstr.length` should be `i < sumstr.length`. That should be causing an infinite loop, so I don't see how you're getting `NaN`.

Comment: You need to use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`. Otherwise it will submit the form and reload the page.

Comment: You have to keep repeating the loop that calculates `total` until the result is a single digit.

Comment: You're getting NaN because of the infinite loop. Eventually `i` goes past the end of `sumstr`, and adding that nonexisting digit results in `NaN`. This is coming from the `console.log(total)` inside the loop.

Comment: Change that to `console.log(i, sumstr[i], total);` and you'll see what's happening.